# MySQL said: Documentation #1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I got this error and it's drive me crazy can anyone help please
MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Fermentum Street’, 'Balvano', 'P5 4MR', 06925697768, 04675467216, 'pure@commod' at line 4

here is the code:

```
DELETE FROM Branch;

INSERT INTO Branch
(branchNo, street, city, postcode, telNo, faxNo, email) values

('B001', ’7 Fermentum Street’, 'Balvano', 'P5 4MR', 06925697768, 04675467216, 'pure@commodsum.org'),
('B002', '66 Rutrum Road’, ’Cropalati', 'WZ5 8BZ', 06061881811, 01762692460, 'felis@eleifend.ca'),
('B003', '21 Fast Road', ‘Manchester’, ’MV3 3AG', 01069686611, 02161256151, 'sed@reetposuere.org'),
('B004', '89 Eros Road’, ’Campano', 'C5K 1AY', 04713509428, 08683205705, 'luctus@utnisi.co.uk'),
('B005’, ’21 Harbour Road’, ’Portsmouth’, ’BS2 7AJ’, 01234567890, 01234567891, ’boats@boatsforus.com’),
('B006', '57 Lectus Street', 'Stornaway', 'B6 5CQ', 03451135340, 04667526884, 'semper@sentuse.com'),
('B007', '1 Dictum’, ’Freetown’, 'FP6 6DB', 02158833092, 03471665376, 'elit@pede.edu’),
('B008’, '32 Site’, ’Williams Lake', 'R8X 4CZ', 07988177200, 02359143354, 'ligula@eu.edu’),
('B009’, '84 Felis Road’, ’France’, ’FD9 8EB', 08233247583, 06991371955, 'ornare@isid.net’),
('B010’, '29 Nascetur Road', 'Archennes', 'X4 7ZZ', 00073470059, 00146946683, 'elit@ittis.ca’),
('B011’, '21 Sed Street’, ’Senftenberg', 'I3X 1JA', 03175544001, 03303607701, 'massa@ading.org’),
('B012’, '36 Arcu Road', ‘Damam’, ’DN0 7ZL', 00748620378, 04347090006, 'justo@semum.edu’),
('B013’, '87 Vitae street’, ’Cerchio', 'D8C 3WL', 07850220231, 09407309996, 'non@ipsumnunc.ca’),
('B014’, '61 Duis Street’, ’Rio', 'WB1 1KF', 04272972336, 03780916592, 'justo@Ediet.net’),
('B015’, '4 Vestibulum Road', 'Stony', 'SO5P 3SL', 03066416104, 06798350690, 'ante@Quisque.org');
```

Comment: You're using quite a nice collection of quotes to enclose strings. Use just `'` for all strings and you should be fine!

Comment: @Sirko: these days customers require not only valid and efficient queries, but also nice looking! Some nice chars just make a query looking much better! ;-)

Comment: Just use an editor with syntax highlighting...

Comment: You use different quotes like `’`  or `‘` to enclose your strings. That's just invalid. Valid are just `'`. So change all quotes to `'` and your query should work.

Comment: can you explain it more because this is my first time using SQL so i do not that much about it

Comment: You have some answers below, which replaced your quotes. Compare them to your original query to see, what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mysql, strings are always delimited with `'`. You have some occurrences of `’` or `‘`.

Replace all those with `'` and your insert will be successful:

```
INSERT INTO Branch(branchNo, street, city, postcode, telNo, faxNo, email) values
  ('B001', '7 Fermentum Street', 'Balvano', 'P5 4MR', 06925697768, 04675467216, 'pure@commodsum.org'),
  ('B002', '66 Rutrum Road', 'Cropalati', 'WZ5 8BZ', 06061881811, 01762692460, 'felis@eleifend.ca'),
  ('B003', '21 Fast Road', 'Manchester', 'MV3 3AG', 01069686611, 02161256151, 'sed@reetposuere.org'),
  ('B004', '89 Eros Road', 'Campano', 'C5K 1AY', 04713509428, 08683205705, 'luctus@utnisi.co.uk'),
  ('B005', '21 Harbour Road', 'Portsmouth', 'BS2 7AJ', 01234567890, 01234567891, 'boats@boatsforus.com'),
  ('B006', '57 Lectus Street', 'Stornaway', 'B6 5CQ', 03451135340, 04667526884, 'semper@sentuse.com'),
  ('B007', '1 Dictum', 'Freetown', 'FP6 6DB', 02158833092, 03471665376, 'elit@pede.edu'),
  ('B008', '32 Site', 'Williams Lake', 'R8X 4CZ', 07988177200, 02359143354, 'ligula@eu.edu'),
  ('B009', '84 Felis Road', 'France', 'FD9 8EB', 08233247583, 06991371955, 'ornare@isid.net'),
  ('B010', '29 Nascetur Road', 'Archennes', 'X4 7ZZ', 00073470059, 00146946683, 'elit@ittis.ca'),
  ('B011', '21 Sed Street', 'Senftenberg', 'I3X 1JA', 03175544001, 03303607701, 'massa@ading.org'),
  ('B012', '36 Arcu Road', 'Damam', 'DN0 7ZL', 00748620378, 04347090006, 'justo@semum.edu'),
  ('B013', '87 Vitae street', 'Cerchio', 'D8C 3WL', 07850220231, 09407309996, 'non@ipsumnunc.ca'),
  ('B014', '61 Duis Street', 'Rio', 'WB1 1KF', 04272972336, 03780916592, 'justo@Ediet.net'),
  ('B015', '4 Vestibulum Road', 'Stony', 'SO5P 3SL', 03066416104, 06798350690, 'ante@Quisque.org');
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ecca6)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

dont use ’ use only '. whereever u have used ’ replace it with '

```
('B001', '7 Fermentum Street', 'Balvano', 'P5 4MR', 06925697768, 04675467216, 'pure@commodsum.org')
```